# Completion Handler not returning the desired values upon completion

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

Having some issue w/ the below code to return the fileList *after* it finishes downloading all the files.
I can get the list of files `dbFileList` in the remote server w/o issues via the completion handler but I'm not able to get the array of the local files `localFileList` *after* I finish downloading whichever missing local copy.

The download (2nd) loop is within the 1st Loop. What do I need to do to have the completion handler only execute upon all files has been downloaded?

```
func dropboxWorkoutList ( userCompletionHandler: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    var dbFileList: [String] = []
    var localFileList: [String] = []

    
    let client  = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
    let separatorString = "=_-_="
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let localDestURL = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Cloud/Dropbox")
    
    
    _ = client?.files.listFolder(path: "/workouts")
      .response { response, error in
        if let result = response {
          for entry in result.entries {
            if let dbFile = entry as? Files.FileMetadata {
              let dbFileNameRev = "\(dbFile.name)\(separatorString)\(dbFile.rev)"
              
              let fullURL = localDestURL.appendingPathComponent(dbFileNameRev)
              let ext = (dbFile.name as NSString).pathExtension
              
              if ext == "mrc" || ext == "zwo" {
                /// append to array if correct file extension
                dbFileList.append(dbFileNameRev)
                
                /// check if file exists in local cache - Download if otherwise
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fullURL) {
                  //  print("::\(#function):: File \"\(dbPathComponent)\" found in cache - \(data) w/ fullURL \(fullURL)")
                  
                  /// Local copy exists of remote file. Append into LocalFile list
                  localFileList.append(dbFileNameRev)
                } else {
                  print("DOWNLOAD   destFileComponents:\(dbFileNameRev)")
                  
                  let destination : (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> URL = { temporaryURL, response in
                    
                    /// Determine if FileExists 
                    do {
                      try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
                        at: localDestURL,
                        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                        attributes: nil
                      )
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                      print("==================")
                      print("= Directory Exists:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                      print("==================")
                    }
                    return fullURL
                  }
                  
                  
                  _ = client?.files.download(path: dbFile.pathLower!, destination: destination)
                    .response { response, error in
                      if let (_, url) = response {
                        print("DOWNLOADED       DropBox File:\(url.lastPathComponent)")
                        /// Downloaded a copy of Remote file. Append into LocalFile list
                        localFileList.append(dbFileNameRev)
                        print("Array           localFileList:\(localFileList)")
                      } else {
                        print("::\(#function):: ERROR downloading file from Dropbox: \(error!)")
                      }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          // return list of files found in DropBox Folder sorted by name
          dbFileList = dbFileList.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 } )
          print("=== Calling Completion Handler ===")
          print("dropboxWorkoutList dbFileList   :\(dbFileList)")
          print("dropboxWorkoutList localFileList:\(localFileList)")
          print("=== Calling Completion Handler ===\n")
//          userCompletionHandler(dbFileList)
          userCompletionHandler(localFileList)
        } else if let error = error {
          print(error)
        }
      }
```

I'm calling the completion handler this way:

```
 dropboxFunc.dropboxWorkoutList() { (value) in
        self.dbWorkoutList = value
        print("--------- dbWorkoutList:\(self.dbWorkoutList)")

        self.vcLibTableView.reloadData()
      }
```

This is what gets printed out at the end of the completion handler block

```
dbFileList   :["file1.mrc", "file2.mrc", "file3.mrc"]
localFileList:["file1.mrc"]
```

the content of localFileList gets returned before it finishes all the downloads.

Comment: Unrelated, but using `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fullURL)` to check existence of local file, that's overkil. You're loading in "RAM" the file, while using `FileManager` to check if file would be much better.

Comment: The issue is that `for entry in result.entries{}` ends BEFORE `client?.files.download(path:destination)` response closure is called. That's why.

Comment: Simplify with: Download all files which aren't local using a `DispatchGroup`. On the notify, return all local files (which should now includes the successfull downloaded files).

Comment: You say you have researched this, but then why is there no DispatchGroup in your code? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DispatchGroup

Comment: @Larme I wrongly thought that the response closure would encompass all the items within the response block. Based on your suggestion, I now know that I needed to research for ```DispatchGroup``` instead of Nested Closures. Thanks for the point in the right direction, I managed to resolve the problem w/ Dispatch Group. Only took me a short time once I knew where to look. (Researching the wrong item didn't help). About the ```let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fullURL)```, there's actually code to parse the File for display. (drawing a chart)

Comment: @Larme If you could put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it